# Why do my textures make randomly colored gaps?

Tags: unity, textures

So in unity, I use a palette to paint a texture, but they create randomly colored gaps like this: [image]

Why is this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rid of texture bleeding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111704/getting-rid-of-texture-bleeding)

Comment: Oh the lines only appear in the dev environment. I put the textures in an atlas, and when I clicked play the lines disappeared. Thank you for answering.